# BASH better way to do a look back?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

hey guys I'm wondering if there is a smart way to look back before a period in bash

```
file='foo'/bar/styles.css?ver=1.4.2

ext=$(echo ${file} | gawk -F  "?" '{print$1}')
echo "${ext##*.}" # css
```

Seems like I should be able to do this all in my expansion somehow?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the goal here, but look at the `basename` command and see if it helps you with what you are trying to do. Otherwise, please provide an explanation of the expected input and the result.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should quote the `?` in `file=...?...`. It's unlikely at best that it'll match anything, but technically it could, and with the right shell options it will cause an error if it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you can do it with just one bash expansion statement (unless they can be nested somehow), works fine with two though

```
$ start=${file%%\?*}; echo ${start##*.}
css
```

Comment: +1 - PEs can't be nested in the general case, and using two of them is exactly what we'd suggest if this question were asked in freenode's #bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy To clarify for anyone that tried nesting and succeeded (like I did), it's because you're using zsh which supports it (bash, ksh, etc don't).